# Can I construct a double order SQL clause in Rails 4? Scope, Arel Table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a small line of code that I am attempting to upgrade from Rails 2 to Rails 4 in a model file.

```
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :project
has_many :topics, :order => 'sticky desc, replied_at desc', :dependent => :destroy do
   def first
     @first_topic ||= find(:first)
   end
 end
```

What I'm trying to refactor and appropriately move to Rails 4 is this small part of the above association.

```
:order => 'sticky desc, replied_at desc'
```

From my Agile Web Development 4 book, I quote

> Just be aware that Rails doesn't know how to handle multiple order or limit clauses, so be sure to use these only once per call chain.

Below is an example scope from the Rails 4 guides

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, -> { order "date_confirmed DESC" }
end
```

With this knowledge can I not refactor the code into something like this as a scope

```
scope :sticky_and_replied_at_desc {order("sticky DESC, replied_at DESC")}
```

Is this not a valid way to refactor this or would I need to break this statement into two scopes and chain them? Perhaps even an arel table? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you can create a double order SQL statement as a scope.

```
has_many :topics, -> {order "sticky DESC, replied_at DESC" }, { dependent: :destroy } do
  def first
    @first_topic ||= find(:first)
  end
end
```

This code seems to work fine.